# Id=' ' within id=' ' with javascript and onmouseover="this.click();" function

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, anchor, href

I am a beginner in Javascript and I am not absolutely sure how to put together the function what I try to achieve.

So, I have a HTML5 page and I must stick to my ID structure as different functions are tied to IDs.

My problem is I have an id within an id (It must stay an ID, it cannot be swapped with class)

E.G.

```
<div id="outterid">
 <a href="#innerid">CLICK ME</a>
  <div id="innerid">
        <p>Hello World</p>
  </div>
</div
```

Where, `<div id=outterid">` pops up as a tooltip (My other javascript takes care of that function. And within that the link `<a href="#innerid">CLICK ME</a>` and the hidden  `<div id=innerid">`.

So when you click `<a href="#innerid">CLICK ME</a>`, `<div id=innerid">`becomes visible. (Note: `<div id="outterid">` is visible, while you are clicking)

So I need to achieve the href="#innerid" through javascript, because at the moment simply href=""

E.G.

```
<a href="#innerid">CLICK ME</a>
```

does not work, because the #innerid within the #outterid.

Also, the 'CLICK ME' link has to be triggered by `onmouseover="this.click();"`. So, the link clicked when the mouse hovers over it.

I hope I managed to clearly explain what is my problem and what result I am looking for.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: You miss the key word `a` before the attribute `href` which will give you this correct html link tag : `<a href="#innerid">CLICK ME</a>`

Comment: Yes, that is correct. My mistake I meant to say <a href="#innerid">CLICK ME</a>

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve ? You didn't describe what the expected and current behaviours were.

Comment: Bartdude, I didn't want to complicate my question with many information, but now I added I hope this clears it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking here about scrolling to the relevant div (e.g. #innerid)? In which case I don't think your problem has anything to do with javascript, but rather you've missed the `a` off of `<href="#innerid">CLICK ME</a>`... I've tried [replicating your problem in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wxLwtakq/) and with `<a href="#innerid">CLICK ME</a>` it scrolls to the correct div regardless of if it's in a nested outer div or not.

Comment: No, when  <a href="#innerid">CLICK ME</a> clicked, my <div id="innerid"><p>Hello World</p></div> (which is hidden)  suppose to appeare. It is one of my tab. It woks correctly if the <div id="InnerID"> is located out of the <div id="outterID"> but as soon as i place it within <div id="outterID"> it stops. Unfortunately, I must jhave it within <div id="outterID">.

Comment: Well you didn't mention anything about trying to toggle visibility in your original post...

You won't be able to see #innerid without having #outerid also visible if it's nested! HTML 101!

Comment: If #outerid is visible, I highly recommend you use jQuery as all you have to do then is have `<span class="clicker">CLICK ME</span>` and the javascript would be `$(".clicker").click(function() { $("#innerid").show(); });`

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what you're after here but i've had a shot. This example will display the #innerid div when you click on the anchor tag. Hopefully this will help you.

```js
function myFunction(href) {
  var id = href.split('#')[1];
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
#innerid { display:none; }
```

```html
<a onclick="myFunction(this.href)" href="#innerid">CLICK ME</a>

<div id="outterid">
  <div id="innerid">
        <p>Hello World</p>
  </div>
</div
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the reply. I tried it. It did not work. However I added the description of the functions of the `<div id="outterid">` and `<div id="innerid">` . It might help to understand, why my href="#innerid" does not work.